# SQL user permission - execute stored procedures

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, permissions

**The problem**

I am attempting to find the best solution to allow some new developers to work with our existing system without giving them full access to our database, however, they will be required to execute pre-written stored procedures.

**Current system**

Our current system is a ASP.NET C# application with a SQL Server 2008 database. We currently have the SQL credentials stored in the `web.config` file which means they could simply read the credentials and access the database.

**What I am trying to achieve**

Is it possible to create an account which can only execute the currently written stored procedures but cannot access the database directly and view the code of the stored procedures, access the tables to view the data or structure and restrict every other sort permission which isn't required?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

You will need to grant `Connect SQL` permission to that login and grant `execute` on those stored procedures you want that login be able to execute.

All other actions under that login will not be possible, including accessing database tables directly and viewing definitions of stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can:
check [Server-Level Roles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188659.aspx) and [Database-Level Roles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121.aspx)